# Forwarded file URL not loading and displaying file in the correct location

Tags: javascript, express, web-development-server

I am hosting a web server using Express JS, and have middleware set up so that all requests to `*.mydomain.com/cdn/*` get forwarded to `cdn.mydomain.com`. In my html file I have the following lines:

```html
<style>
  @import url("/cdn/style.css");
</style>
<script src="/cdn/script.js"></script>
```

However, when looking at `Developer Tools > Sources` on the site, it shows the css file as `cdn.mydomain.com/style.css` but the javascript file as `mydomain.com/cdn/script.js`.

When looking at the network tab, the request gets properly forwarded then loaded, with the final `Request URL` header showing `https://cdn.mydomain.com/script.js`.

Is this performance expected of javascript files or is something playing up? Thanks in advance for any advice you're able to offer.